# How to prove MIP is in NEXP

Tags: complexity-classes, nondeterminism, interactive-proof-systems

I was trying to understand the proof of MIP is inside NEXP. I was referring to Rutger's university scribes ([link](https://sites.math.rutgers.edu/%7Esk1233/courses/topics-S17/lec9.pdf)). They define MIP as a class with exponential proof, but that is not the definition I am familiar with. It is much easier to understand why that definition would be in NEXP, but I am unclear on how having polynomial interactions with multiple provers translates to this or the NEXP definition.

It would be great if someone links me to a source that has an easier understanding of this, I tried understanding the original paper by Babai *et. al* but I was not able to follow through.